# How to change the direction of text input. imask.js?

Tags: javascript

Plugin https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs.

By default, the text is entered from left to right, and the cursor moving to the right replaces the right-standing mask character. How to do the opposite, the cursor is set to the right, moves to the left, replacing the characters on the left?

```
var element = document.getElementById('elem');
var maskOptions = {
mask: '0000000000',
lazy: false,
placeholderChar: '0',
overwrite: true
};
var mask = IMask(element, maskOptions);
```

Comment: `direction: rtl`?

Comment: By the way, if you set the attribute `dir="rtl"`, the cursor is on the right but the text input is on the left.

`<input type="text" dir="rtl" id="elem">`

Comment: I meant in the css: `#elem {direction: rtl}`

Comment: @MoshFeu `direction: rtl` - there is no such option in the plugin

Comment: @MoshFeu `direction: rtl` work as dir="rtl"

Comment: Interesting. without the `lazy` it's working well.

Comment: `lazy` allows you to display a placeholder

Comment: Right. I couldn't find this in the docs, so it's probably feature request..